# I want to manage flex in css

Tags: css, flexbox

I need flex box like screenshot I create demo but I don`t need all item together

screenshot : [image]

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/parthjasani/103t93xd/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Flexbox, auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) got an update and made them even more useful than in block flow.

In this case, if to add an auto margin to the first and last child, they will be pushed to the beginning/end of their parent, and at the same time push the two in the middle to the center.

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;        removed, not needed  */
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.flex-container > div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
</div>
```

---

Or the auto margin can be set on the two in the middle and render the same result.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;        removed, not needed  */
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
</div>
```

---

Or on the 2nd and 4th (with `nth-child(even)`).

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;        removed, not needed  */
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use margin on first and last inner `div` element.

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-container > div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.flex-container > div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
</div>
```